# finding multiples close to a value in r

Tags: r

I want to find the closest number given that I have three numbers `x`, `y` and `z` .  I want to find the closest multiple to `z` which is closest to `x^y`.

Some examples:

```
x <- 349
y <- 1
z <- 4

x <- 395
y <- 1
z <- 7

x <- 4
y <- -2
z <- 2
```

The result should look like:

- the closest multiple of `4` to `349` is `348`
- the closest multiple of `7` to `395` is `392`
- the closest multiple of `2` to `1/16` is `0`

Comment: I'm not sure what these constraints mean. What's `T`?

Comment: They mean very little, all the answers given seem correct.

Comment: I removed them to stop any confusion :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Nice question btw. (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use

```
f = function(x, y, z) round(x^y/z)*z
```

For example

```
f(349,1,4)
# [1] 348

f(395,1,7)
# [1] 392

f(4,-2,2)
# [1] 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = function(x, y, z) {
    tmp = x^y
    r = tmp %% z  #take modulus to find remainder
    tmp - r       #subtract remainder from x^y
}

foo(4, -2, 2)
#[1] 0
```

Comment: If we use the word *closest*, then `foo(351, 4)` should return 352, shouldn't it?

Comment: @d.b (+1) I think your first version (pre-edit) was correct `f <- function(x, y, z) x^y - x^y %% z`. which returned `0` for `foo(4, -2, 2)` (consistent with OPs expected output).

Comment: I don't know, just trying to interpret the OP.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use bitwise OR (assuming `x^y` and `z` are natural numbers)

```
f2 <- function(x, y, z) bitwOr((x^y) - 1, z - 1) + 1 - z
f2(349, 1, 4)
#[1] 348
f2(395, 1, 7)
#[1] 392
f2(4, -2, 2)
#[1] 0
```

Comment: Very clever.  But I don't think it plays nicely with negative values.  E.g. `f2(2,2,-2)`or `f2(-2,3,2)`

Comment: @dww Hmm. What would be your expected output for the tuple `2, 2, -2`?

Comment: I think 2^2 is 4, so the answer (nearest multiple of `-2`) is `4` - i.e. `-2 * -2`